# Running MSSQL properties via Doctrine

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

After multiple attempt to handle properties and Doctrine with MSSQL, I'm about to give up

If I'm running the query below, the result is just an empty array.

```
$q = $statm->prepare("
        set quoted_identifier on
        set ansi_warnings on
        set ansi_padding on
        set ansi_nulls on
        set concat_null_yields_null on
        SELECT TOP 10 Id FROM [User]");
```

but if I'm running the query without all the properties, then it will return the 10 rows I've requested.

I'm using this Driver for Symfony2:

Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib\Driver

Comment: Maybe you forgot a `;` symbol at the end of each statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Before the query is running, I need to execute the property query first by doing so:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->exec("set quoted_identifier on;
    set ansi_warnings on;
    set ansi_padding on;
    set ansi_nulls on;
    set concat_null_yields_null on;");
```